# How to configure TwinCAT EtherCAT PDOs?

Tags: automation, plc, twincat, ethercat

I am having a problem to access to the rest of the memory of a etherCAT device, since it already comes with a default PDO configuration, but when i try to edit this configuration, it won't change and the device stops working correctly unless i use the default configuration again.

Is this the correct way of doing it, or is there any other mwthod to achieve this?. Or maybe, should I edit the ESI field to upload this properties to the device?

I already tried what beckhoff documentation says about adding new PDO directories, but i still get the same result. I also tried using the same directories and properties to the previous configuration adding the directories of the device that I also want to read and write.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to do and link/mention what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issues when i tried to modify different IO or motor modules `PDO`, an the official answer from Beckhoff is the following:

If in the documentation is explicit mentioned that another `COE` data can be added to the `PDO` configuration than it will work as expected (typical examples are the Safety modules) if is not mentioned you would have to read the desired variables or values using the function blocks for reading and Writing `COE` data like `FB_CoERead()` and `FB_CoEWrite()`

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_mc2_drive/2297741579.html&id=

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_mc2_drive/2297743499.html&id=

Regarding your question on how you can configure it, here is an example from beckhoff infosys:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/el6695/1317558667.html&id=